# How to remove the border around a tab header's contents in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-interface

I am a beginner to WPF. I have a tab header in my tab control with title "Test" and also a button inside the tab. I am trying to make the entire tab dark however there is still a small white background surrounding the tab header's contents. How can I get rid of this/re-color it?

[image]

Here is my resource dictionary:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TabItem.Selected.Background" Color="{DynamicResource Border}"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TabItem.Selected.Border" Color="{DynamicResource Border}"/>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border x:Name="border" Background="{DynamicResource Border}">
                        <ContentPresenter>
                            <ContentPresenter.Content>
                                <TextBlock Margin="0" FontSize="13px" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" Padding="0"/>
                            </ContentPresenter.Content>
                        </ContentPresenter>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    
    <Style x:Key="TabControlTheme" TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource TabItem.Selected.Background}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource TabItem.Selected.Border}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource ForegroundColor}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
                    <Grid x:Name="templateRoot" ClipToBounds="true" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="ColumnDefinition0"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="ColumnDefinition1" Width="0"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition x:Name="RowDefinition0" Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition x:Name="RowDefinition1" Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <TabPanel x:Name="headerPanel" Background="Transparent" Grid.Column="0" IsItemsHost="true" Margin="2,2,2,0" Grid.Row="0" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1" Panel.ZIndex="1"/>
                        <Border x:Name="contentPanel" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Grid.Column="0" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" Grid.Row="1" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="2" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_SelectedContentHost" ContentSource="SelectedContent" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Bottom">
                            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="headerPanel" Value="1"/>
                            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="contentPanel" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition0" Value="*"/>
                            <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition1" Value="Auto"/>
                            <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="headerPanel" Value="2,0,2,2"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Left">
                            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="headerPanel" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="contentPanel" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Grid.Column" TargetName="headerPanel" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Grid.Column" TargetName="contentPanel" Value="1"/>
                            <Setter Property="Width" TargetName="ColumnDefinition0" Value="Auto"/>
                            <Setter Property="Width" TargetName="ColumnDefinition1" Value="*"/>
                            <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition0" Value="*"/>
                            <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition1" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="headerPanel" Value="2,2,0,2"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Right">
                            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="headerPanel" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="contentPanel" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Grid.Column" TargetName="headerPanel" Value="1"/>
                            <Setter Property="Grid.Column" TargetName="contentPanel" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Width" TargetName="ColumnDefinition0" Value="*"/>
                            <Setter Property="Width" TargetName="ColumnDefinition1" Value="Auto"/>
                            <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition0" Value="*"/>
                            <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition1" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="headerPanel" Value="0,2,2,2"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
            
            
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I have tried to color the background using a style in a resource dictionary for a tab control. That did not get rid of the white surrounding area so I tried to create a style for a tab item, which still does not get rid of the white.